# Getting two different means in R using same numbers

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the mean of some grouped data, but I'm running into an issue where the mean generated using `base::mean()` is generating a different value than when I use `base:rowMeans()` or try to replicate the mean in Excel.

Here's the code with a simplified data frame looking at just a small piece of the data:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1101372,
                 "Q1" = 5.996667,
                 "Q2" = 6.005556,
                 "Q3" = 5.763333)

avg1 <- df %>%
  summarise(new_avg = mean(Q1,
                           Q2,
                           Q3)) # Returns a value of 5.99667

avg2 <- rowMeans(df[,2:4]) # Returns a value of 5.921852
```

The value in `avg2` is what I get when I use AVERAGE in Excel, but I can't figure out why `mean()` is not generating the same number.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the `mean` is taking only the first argument i.e. Q1 as 'x' because the usage for `?mean` is

> mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...)

i.e. the second and third argument are different.  In the OP's code, x will be taken as "Q1", `trim` as "Q2" and so on..  The `...` at the end also means that the user can supply `n` number of parameters without any error and leads to confusions like this (if we don't check the usage)

We can specify the data as `.`, subset the columns of interest and use that in `rowMeans`

```
df %>% 
    summarise(new_avg = rowMeans(.[-1]))
```

This would be more efficient. But, if we want to use `mean` as such, then do a `rowwise`

```
df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   summarise(new_avg = mean(c(Q1, Q2, Q3)))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  new_avg
#     <dbl>
#1    5.92
```

---

Or convert to 'long' format and then do the `group_by` 'ID' and get the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%  # can skip this step if there is only a single row
    summarise(new_avg = mean(value))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      ID new_avg
#    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 1101372    5.92
```

Comment: Thank you for the variations. I used variation #2 and was able to use `mutate` instead of `summarise` but it got me on the right track for the larger problem.